# 4.5 .NET installed but not visible for Asus utility

Tags: .net-framework, asus-laptop

Trying to install Asus utilities for my PC'm motherboard in Windows 10 . Got error:

```
The following application requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5: Intel® Small Business Advantage.

Please install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 from Microsoft Download Center to run this application correctly.
```

I tried to install .NET 4.5, but got report that it is already installed. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10

Comment: After I have removed AsusSetup.ini I got error:
`Does not support this Operating System: WNT_10.0P_64`

Comment: `Small Business Advantage` is the reason it does not support Windows 10.  I am not sure the reason you are removing a required .ini file though.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to install .NET 4.5, but it reported that it is already
>   installed.

It's not possible to install .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 10. Windows 10 already has .NET Framework 4.6.x+ installed.

> How to solve this problem?

`Intel® Small Business Advantage` does not support Windows 10.  `Intel® Small Business Advantage` was discontinued in 2016. You are not going to be able to install it on Windows 10. The installer is looking for the key that indicates that .NET Framework 4.5 is installed since that key does not exist, it cannot be installed on Windows 10.  Since it's discontinued it shouldn't be installed anyways.

However, you should be able to modify the installation of the ASUS utility and configure it so it doesn't even attempt to install that tool.  You cannot even download the last version that was released because Intel removed it from their website.  *My suggestion is to not even install the ASUS utility.*

> - June 18, 2016 – Intel® Small Business Advantage software will no longer be available for download from Intel.
> - September 18, 2016 – Intel customer support will no longer accept customer contacts for Intel® Small Business Advantage. Support
>     includes phone, email, web submission, and chat.
> - November 18, 2016 – Intel® Small Business Advantage support site will become inactive. Basic troubleshooting and general information
>     articles will remain available.

- Q: Will there be any final releases of Intel® Small Business Advantage?
- A: The latest version of Intel® Small Business Advantage released by Intel is 4.1.42. There will be no further releases or updates to the product.

[Source](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000021965/software.html)